# Uso do `self->` ao invés de `self.`

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, ios, objective-c

Estou trabalhando em um app que não foi eu que iniciei o código e estou com problemas em relação ao uso do comando **`self->`**. 
Em alguns ponto do código estou encontrando variáveis declaradas com ***`self->`*** ao invés de **`self.`**.

```objc
@interface UNBill ()
{
    NSMutableArray *billArray;
}
@end
...
- (void)payment:(id)billArray people:(int)peopleRow value:(NSString *)amountPay
{
    [[self->billArray objectAtIndex:peopleRow] setObject:amountPay forKey:columnPayment];
}
```

Pelo que identifiquei até agora o `self->` esta informando ao compilador que é o `billArray` global está sendo usado e não o `billArray` do método, mas agora preciso utilizar o `billArray` do método, e informando apenas `[billArray objectAtIndex:i]` estou tomando warning.

Alguém sabe me explicar como funciona?

Comment: Aqui tem uma explicação muito boa sobre isto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072688/dot-operator-and-arrow-operator-use-in-c-vs-objective-c

Comment: Olhando melhor o código, vi que existe o Array `billArray` como variável global e como parâmetro de um método. O comando `self->` esta sendo usando dentro do método para identificar que está sendo utilizado a variável global e não a de parâmetro do método.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vou dividir esta resposta em três partes: a diferença entre `self->` e `self.`, o aviso do compilador e como evitá-lo, e comentários acerca desta pergunta e outras respostas.

---

### A diferença

`self->` é usado para acessar uma variável de instância (*ivar, instance variable*) diretamente dentro de um método da mesma classe. No seu exemplo, a classe `UNBill` possui uma variável de instância chamada `billArray`. Métodos dessa classe podem acessá-la diretamente pelo nome `bilArray` ou o nome qualificado `self->billArray`, que significa a variável de instância `billArray` pertencente ao objeto atual (`self`). O uso do operador `->` dá-se porque `self` é um ponteiro para o objeto atual, esse objeto pode ser interpretado como uma estrutura em C, e `billArray` pode ser interpretado como um membro dessa estrutura. De fato, a maior parte dos objetos em Objective-C podem ser interpretados como uma instância de estrutura.

`self.` é utilizado para enviar uma mensagem ao objeto atual. De forma geral, a notação `objeto.x` numa expressão é uma alternativa para `[objeto x]`, onde `x` não tem parâmetros. Um caso comum de mensagem sem parâmetros são os métodos de leitura de propriedades, tradicionalmente chamados de *getters*: não têm parâmetros e devolvem o valor da propriedade. Além disso, quando essa notação é usada como a expressão à esquerda numa atribuição (e.g. `objeto.x = valor`), essa atribuição é traduzida como `[objeto setX:valor]`, onde `-setX:` é um *setter* que recebe um único parâmetro.

Por exemplo, considere a classe abaixo:

```
@interface Cliente : NSObject
@property (copy) NSString *nome
@end
```

Por padrão, o compilador sintetiza dois métodos de acesso para a propriedade `nome`: o *getter*

```
- (NSString *)nome;
```

e o *setter*

```
- (void)setNome:(NSString *)nome;
```

bem como uma variável de instância chamada `_nome` para armazenar o nome.

Neste caso, clientes da classe podem usar a notação `.` para usar os métodos de acesso:

```
Pessoa *pessoa = [Pessoa new];
pessoa.nome = @"João"; // equivale a [pessoa setNome:@"João"]
NSLog(@"O nome é %@", pessoa.nome); // equivale a [pessoa nome]
```

Internamente, métodos dessa classe podem usar a mesma notação para acessar a propriedade, desta vez com `self`:

```
@implementation Pessoa
- (void)imprimirDados {
    NSLog(@"Dados da pessoa");
    NSLog(@"Nome: %@", self.nome);   
}
@end
```

Alternativamente, o método acima poderia acessar a variável de instância diretamente sem ter que passar pelo *getter*:

```
- (void)imprimirDados {
    NSLog(@"Dados da pessoa");
    NSLog(@"Nome: %@", _nome);
}
```

E a variável de instância pode ser qualificada com `self->`:

```
- (void)imprimirDados {
    NSLog(@"Dados da pessoa");
    NSLog(@"Nome: %@", self->_nome);
}
```

Resumindo: `self->_nome` acessa diretamente a variável de instância `_nome`, enquanto que `self.nome` envia uma mensagem chamada `nome` para o objeto atual, que por sua vez executa o método chamado `nome`.

---

### O aviso

O seu exemplo possui um característica que pode ser confusa: o nome da variável de instância `billArray` coincide com o nome do primeiro parâmetro do método `-payment:people:value:`. Quando se escreve `self->billArray` dentro do método, é óbvio que se está referindo à variável de instância. Quando se escreve apenas `billArray`, qual valor é usado: o da variável de instância ou o do parâmetro? Como isto pode não ser claro para todos os programadores, o compilador, através do aviso `-Wshadow-ivar`, alerta que a declaração local de `billArray` (como parâmetro) ofusca a variável de instância -- isto significa que `billArray` refere-se ao parâmetro. Se é este o comportamento que você deseja, você pode ignorar o aviso. Se você quiser eliminar o aviso, você tem três opções: trocar os nomes de tal forma que o nome da variável de instância seja distinto do nome do parâmetro, usar `-Wno-shadow-ivar` ao compilar aquele arquivo, ou usar pragmas para desabilitar o aviso apenas naquele método:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wshadow-ivar"
- (void)payment:(id)billArray people:(int)peopleRow value:(NSString *)amountPay
{
    [[billArray objectAtIndex:peopleRow] setObject:amountPay forKey:columnPayment];
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

No seu caso, talvez você não queira adotar propriedades e/ou variáveis de instância prefixadas com `_`. Uma alternativa é trocar o nome do parâmetro de `billArray` para `aBillArray` ou `pBillArray`. De qualquer forma, recomendo trocar um dos nomes em vez de desabilitar o aviso.

---

### Miscelânea

Algumas observações quanto à pergunta original e outras respostas:

> o comando `self->`

`self->` não é um comando. `self` é uma identificador reservado criado automaticamente pelo compilador para se referir ao objeto atual. Aliás, esse identificador é na verdade o nome do primeiro parâmetro escondido em todos os métodos em Objective-C. `->` é um operador do C para desreferenciar uma estrutura e acessar um membro dela.

> `self->` esta informando ao compilador que é o `billArray` global

`billArray` não é (uma variável) global: é uma variável de instância, similar a um membro de estrutura em C.

> o que está te atrapalhando é quanto ao tipo da variável do billArray do método que é id e como ID é apenas um objeto sem classe (semelhante a var em outras linguagens) tu não pode chamar métodos de outras classes como as do `NSMutableArray` nele

Não é o caso. Objetos cujo tipo sejam `id`, que é o tipo genérico para objetos, não têm verificação de conformidade com interface, então o compilador aceita a composição de qualquer tipo de mensagem para aquele objeto desde que o seletor correspondente tenha sido previamente declarado. Por exemplo, `-[NSArray objectAatIndex:]` possui tipo de retorno `id`. Você pode enviar qualquer mensagem (com seletor previamente declarado) ao objeto retornado por esse método e, sendo sintaxe válida em Objective-C, não recebe aviso ou erro do compilador. Para o código abaixo:

```
NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Uma string"];
NSLog(@"Length is %lu", [[a objectAtIndex:0] length]);
```

o compilador não emite aviso algum. O que ocorre é verificação em tempo de execução: se o objeto (de tipo `id`) não responde à mensagem com seletor `length`, ocorre erro durante a execução.

> o uso do `->` é apenas um acesso via ponteiro, muito comum em C++ por exemplo. O código é totalmente compatível com Objective-C, porém recomendo evitar, para facilitar um padrão e clareza de código

Há quem recomende sempre usar `self->` justamente para deixar **mais claro** que se está acessando diretamente uma variável de instância.

> Recomendo que você altere o nome do parametro do seu método para `pBillArray`, é o costume para nomes de parâmetros no ObjC.

Costumes variam. O costume antigo da Apple não era prefixar com `p`, mas sim com artigo indefinido (`aBillArray`). O costume mais recente da Apple é não usar prefixo algum nos nomes de parâmetros.

> Também declare suas "instâncias de classe" sempre utilizando `@property`, assim o compilador irá criar automaticamente os getters e setters para você, fazendo com que você seja capaz de acessar o `billArray` utilizando apenas `self.billArray`. Além de facilitar o uso, esse é o uso padrão no que chamamos de "Objective C moderno".

“instâncias de classe” — na verdade, são chamadas de variáveis de instância em Objective-C, similares a atributos (de instância) em outras linguagens orientadas a objetos.

Quanto a propriedades, este é um tópico um pouco (bem pouco, eu diria) controverso. De forma geral, a Apple tem recomendado sempre usar propriedades em vez de variáveis de instância diretamente. Essa recomendação era mais importante antes do advento do ARC porque os *getters* e *setters* gerados pelo compilador faziam o gerenciamento (manual) de memória, enviando `retain` e `release` quando apropriado. Com o advento do ARC, esse gerenciamento acontece automaticamente mesmo quando se usa a variável de instância diretamente.

Note que há uma corrente filosófica que advoga que nenhum método além do *getter* e do *setter*, nem mesmo da própria classe, deve acessar diretamente variáveis de instância. Isto traria mais robustez porque qualquer alteração referente àquela variável ficaria localizada apenas em seu *getter* e *setter*. Por outro lado, sempre usar *getter* e *setter* em vez da variável de instância tem custo: o John McCall, um dos engenheiros da Apple que trabalha no Clang/LLVM, detalhou isto numa lista de discussão. Reproduzo aqui [as observações dele](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2013/Mar/msg00174.html):

> Right.  There are a lot of things that are hard to individually measure but which make a noticeable difference in the aggregate.
>
> Properties affect performance in a lot of ways:
>
> 1. As already discussed, sending a message to do a load/store is slower than just doing the load/store inline.
> 2. Sending a message to do a load/store is also quite a bit more code that needs to be kept in i-cache:  even if the getter/setter added zero extra instructions beyond just the load/store, there'd be a solid half-dozen extra instructions in the caller to set up the message send and handle the result.
> 3. Sending a message forces an entry for that selector to be kept in the method cache, and that memory generally sticks around in d-cache.  This increases launch time, increases the static memory usage of your app, and makes context switches more painful.  Since the method cache is specific to the dynamic class for an object, this problem increases the more you use KVO on it.
> 4. Sending a message forces all values in the function to be spilled to the stack (or kept in callee-save registers, which just means spilling at a different time).
> 5. Sending a message can have arbitrary side-effects and therefore forces the compiler to reset all of its assumptions about non-local memory.
> 6. A message send can have arbitrary side-effects and therefore cannot be hoisted, sunk, re-ordered, coalesced, or eliminated.
> 7. In ARC, the result of a message send will always get retained, either by the callee or the caller, even for +0 returns:  even if the method doesn't retain/autorelease its result, the caller doesn't know that and has to try to take action to prevent the result from getting autoreleased.  This can never be eliminated because message sends are not statically analyzable.
> 8. In ARC, because a setter method generally takes its argument at +0, there is no way to "transfer" a retain of that object (which, as discussed above, ARC usually has) into the ivar, so the value generally has to get retain/released twice.
>
> None of this means that they're always bad, of course — there are a lot of good reasons to use properties.  Just keep in mind that, like many other language features, they're not free.
>
> John.

Suponho que a maior parte dos aplicativos não seja prejudicada pela perda de desempenho advinda do uso de propriedades, mas é bom saber caso você encontre uma situação de processamento intensivo. E esse tipo de perda de desempenho é difícil de medir mais tarde com Instruments porque, num aplicativo com várias propriedades, a perda de desempenho, mesmo que notável, fica diluída.

---

Resumão: se puder, use propriedades. Caso contrário, renomeie ou a variável de instância (e.g. `_billArray`) ou o parâmetro (e.g. `aBillArray` ou `pBillArray`).

Answer (score 1):

```
**NSMutableArray** *billArray;

(void)payment:(**id**)billArray
```

O motivo dos seus warnings não tem relação com ele estar usando ponteiro (`->`) ou não nesse caso. Por mais que o padrão seja usar `[[self billArray] objectAtIndex:i]` ou `[self.billArray objectAtIndex:i]` ou apenas `billArray` (dependendo de quem tu quer acessar) o que está te atrapalhando é quanto ao tipo da variável do billArray do método que é id e como ID é apenas um objeto sem classe (semelhante a `var` em outras linguagens) tu não pode chamar métodos de outras classes como as do `NSMutableArray` nele.

#### Como resolver?

Em primeiro lugar você precisa converter o id billArray para um `NSMutableArray` ou `NSArray` e após isso usá-lo normalmente. Até um cast resolve.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente vale comentar que o uso do `->`é apenas um acesso via ponteiro, muito comum em C++ por exemplo. O código é totalmente compatível com Objective-C, porém recomendo evitar, para facilitar um padrão e clareza de código.

Já sobre o `self`, sim, ele indica que você está acessando o atributo da classe ao invés da instância definida no escopo do seu método. Recomendo que você altere o nome do parametro do seu método para `pBillArray`, é o costume para nomes de parâmetros no ObjC.

Também declare suas "instâncias de classe" sempre utilizando `@property`, assim o compilador irá criar automaticamente os getters e setters para você, fazendo com que você seja capaz de acessar o `billArray` utilizando apenas `self.billArray`. Além de facilitar o uso, esse é o uso padrão no que chamamos de "Objective C moderno".

Já sobre o seu warning, você precisa dar mais detalhes, no mínimo informar qual o warning que está sendo apresentado.